# How do I mount a mountable application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've created a simple mountable application in rails 3.1.3 using command:

> $ rails plugin new appToMount --mountable

Than I added some MVC to it. And now I want to mount it to another normal Rails application. The problem is I have no idea how to do this. I tried asking google, but I failed. There are plenty of examples how to create mountable app, but none explaining how to mount it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it to the `config/routes.rb` of your rails app. Something like the following:

```
mount AppToMount::Engine, :at => '/'
```

And I recommend you to package your engine as a gem. You can use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to create the new gem with the command

```
bundle new app_to_mount
```

And finally, you should add the Gem to your gemfile, using the path option. Like in the following:

```
gem 'app_to_mount', path: '/your/home/app_to_mount'
```